# Obtaining a target number only using the operations ×2, ×3, and +1

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded, dynamic-programming

> **Problem Introduction**
>
> You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following
>   three operations with the current number x: multiply x by 2, multiply
>   x by 3, or add 1 to x. Your goal is given a positive integer n, find
>   the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n
>   starting from the number 1.
>
> **Task:** Given an integer n, compute the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n starting from the number 1.
>
> **Input Format:** The input consists of a single integer \$1 <=n <= 10^6.\$
>
> **Output:** Print the sequence of intermediate numbers. For example for input \$ n=96234\$, output is *1 3 9 10 11 22 66 198 594 1782 5346
>   16038 16039 32078 96234* or *1 3 9 10 11 33 99 297 891 2673 8019 16038
>   16039 48117 96234*. Both are valid output.

Now I have designed an algorithm and am finding intermediate numbers for each and every number between 1 and n. It is giving me time limit exceeded error. How can I improve its efficiency?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
void primitive_calculator(int64_t number)
{
        std::vector<int64_t> min_steps(number+1,INT_MAX);
        std::list<int64_t>* path=new std::list<int64_t>[number+1];
        min_steps[0]=0; min_steps[1]=0;
        path[0].push_back(0);
        path[1].push_back(1);
        for(int i=2;i<=number;i++)
        {
            if(i%3==0)
            {
                if(min_steps[i/3] < min_steps[i])
                {
                        min_steps[i]=min_steps[i/3]+1;
                        path[i]=path[i/3];
                        path[i].push_back(i);
                }
            }
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                if( min_steps[i/2] < min_steps[i])
                {
                        min_steps[i]=min_steps[i/2]+1;
                        path[i]=path[i/2];
                        path[i].push_back(i);
                }
            }
            if( min_steps[i-1] < min_steps[i])
            {
                min_steps[i]=min_steps[i-1]+1;
                path[i]=path[i-1];
                path[i].push_back(i);
            }
    }
    std::cout<<min_steps[number]<<"\n";
    while(!path[number].empty())
    {
            std::cout<<path[number].front()<<" ";
            path[number].pop_front();
    }
}
int main()
{
    int64_t number;
    std::cin>>number;
    primitive_calculator(number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For each `i = 0...number`, your method stores a `std::list` containing
the complete sequence of intermediate numbers from `1` to `i`. Each list is created by
copying the list from the optimal predecessor and appending `i`.
Even for a single `i`, `path[i]` may be assigned a new list up to
three times.

That is a lot of copying which consumes a lot of time.
It can be improved by choosing a different data structure:
For each number, store only the "optimal predecessor". 
This requires less memory *and* less copying.
 For the final number,
the sequence of intermediate numbers can then be reconstructed by traversing the predecessors from `number` to `1`, and printing
the numbers in reverse order.

More remarks:

- The use of integer types is not consistent. You use `int64_t`
  at most places, but `int i` as the loop variable, and 
  `INT_MAX` as initial value. –
  For `n` in the given range 1...10^6, `int32_t` is sufficiently large.
- The initialization of all elements in `min_steps` to `INT_MAX`
  can be avoided by testing `i - 1` as predecessor first.
- Coding style: There should be more space around operators 
  and keywords.

The function then would look like this:

```
void primitive_calculator(int32_t number)
{
    std::vector<int32_t> min_steps(number + 1);
    std::vector<int32_t> predecessor(number + 1);

    for (int32_t i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        min_steps[i] = min_steps[i-1] + 1;
        predecessor[i] = i - 1;
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            if (min_steps[i/3] < min_steps[i]) {
                min_steps[i] = min_steps[i/3] + 1;
                predecessor[i] = i/3;
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            if (min_steps[i/2] < min_steps[i]) {
                min_steps[i] = min_steps[i/2] + 1;
                predecessor[i] = i/2;
            }
        }
    }


    std::cout << min_steps[number] << "\n";

    std::list<int32_t> sequence;
    for (int32_t i = number; i != 0; i = predecessor[i]) {
        sequence.push_front(i);
    }
    for (auto it = sequence.begin(); it != sequence.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it  << " ";
    }
}
```

For `number = 96234`, this reduced the execution time
from 0.13 seconds with your code to about 0.001 seconds.

The measurement was done on a MacBook with this simple code:

```
int32_t number = 96234;
const clock_t begin_time = clock();
primitive_calculator(number);
const clock_t end_time = clock();
std::cout << "\ntime: " << float( end_time - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
```

Comment: How did you calculate execution time?

Comment: @A.Gautam: See update.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> void primitive_calculator(int64_t number)
> {
>         std::vector<int64_t> min_steps(number+1,INT_MAX);
>         std::list<int64_t>* path=new std::list<int64_t>[number+1];
>         min_steps[0]=0; min_steps[1]=0;
>         path[0].push_back(0);
>         path[1].push_back(1);
>         for(int i=2;i<=number;i++)
>         {
>             if(i%3==0)
>             {
>                 if(min_steps[i/3] < min_steps[i])
>                 {
>                         min_steps[i]=min_steps[i/3]+1;
>                         path[i]=path[i/3];
>                         path[i].push_back(i);
>                 }
>             }
>             if(i%2==0)
>             {
>                 if( min_steps[i/2] < min_steps[i])
>                 {
>                         min_steps[i]=min_steps[i/2]+1;
>                         path[i]=path[i/2];
>                         path[i].push_back(i);
>                 }
>             }
>             if( min_steps[i-1] < min_steps[i])
>             {
>                 min_steps[i]=min_steps[i-1]+1;
>                 path[i]=path[i-1];
>                 path[i].push_back(i);
>             }
>     }
>     std::cout<<min_steps[number]<<"\n";
>     while(!path[number].empty())
>     {
>             std::cout<<path[number].front()<<" ";
>             path[number].pop_front();
>     }
> }
> ```

Even assuming you needed to maintain the `path` list, this isn't the most efficient way to do so.  Consider

```
void primitive_calculator(int32_t number)
{
    std::list<int32_t>* path = new std::list<int32_t>[number+1];

    path[1].push_back(1);

    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {
        std::size_t previous = i - 1;

        if ((i%3 == 0) && (path[i/3].size() < path[previous].size()))
        {
            previous = i/3;
        }

        if ((i%2 == 0) && (path[i/2].size() < path[previous].size()))
        {
            previous = i/2;
        }

        path[i] = path[previous];
        path[i].push_back(i);
    }

    std::cout << path[number].size() - 1 << '\n';
    while (!path[number].empty())
    {
        std::cout << path[number].front() << ' ';
        path[number].pop_front();
    }
}
```

This saves allocating and initializing the `min_steps` vector.  Instead, it assumes that the choice is going to be to subtract one and uses that as the basis for comparison.  This works because you can always subtract one.  The size of the `path` list is one more than the value that we want, but so long as we compare consistent values, it works.

Your original version could copy the `path` list up to three times per iteration.  This version will only copy once.  And only insert once.

I switched from `int64_t` to `int32_t` because thirty-one bits is plenty to hold a number as high as two billion, much less a million.  And this should use less space (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize by promoting 32 bits to 64 or more bits for some reason).

This is not to say that this version is the most efficient.  It's not.  Saving the fewest steps and the previous number is going to be more space efficient and likely more time efficient.  It is more efficient than your version though.

For better separation of concerns, consider returning `path[number]` rather than displaying output in this function.  Then you can do the display elsewhere.  That won't matter for this problem, but it is a good habit for other problems.  It essentially makes the function more useful.

I'd prefer a different name for this function, e.g. `find_shortest_path` or `calculate_fewest_steps`.  As a rule of thumb, functions should have verb names.  They do things.  I would expect a `primitive_calculator` to be some kind of object, as nouns denote objects.  They are things.  Also, `primitive_calculator` doesn't tell me much about what you are calculating.